# Looping through a mutidimentional array in python

Tags: python

How do i achieve line 9 and 10 i.e the two `for` loops in python

```
matrix = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12]
]

newMatrix = []

for (i=0; i < len(matrix); i++):
    for (j=0; j < len(matrix[i]); j++):
        newMatrix[j][i] = matrix[i][j]
print newMatrix
```

PS: i know i can do `[[row[i] for row in matrix] for i in range(4)]` but how i do only using for loops

Comment: Matrix transformation can be done this way: `zip(*matrix)`

Comment: @Satoru.Logic: this should be an answer.

Comment: @thg435 Ok, now I've added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `range` (or `xrange`).

```
for i in range(len(matrix)):
  for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
```

FYI, assigning to `newMatrix[i][j]` will fail, because `newMatrix` is an empty `list`. You need to add a new empty `list` to `newMatrix` for every row and then append the new value to that list in every iteration.

Comment: @WebDeveloper: I think I made that pretty clear in my answer. What part of it do you not understand? How have you tried to code it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`enumerate()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) to loop over both the matrix values and give you indices:

```
newMatrix = [[0] * len(matrix) for _ in xrange(len(matrix[0]))]
for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
    for j, value in enumerate(row):
        newMatrix[j][i] = value
```

This outputs:

```
[[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 7, 11], [4, 8, 12]]
```

Because you are addressing rows and columns in the new matrix directly, you need to have initialized that new matrix with empty values first. The list comprehension on the first line of my example does this for you. It creates a new matrix that is (*y*, *x*) in size, given an input matrix of size (*x*, *y*).

Alternatively, you can avoid explicit looping altogether by (ab)using the [`zip` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip):

```
newMatrix = zip(*matrix)
```

which takes each row of `matrix` and groups each column in those rows into new rows.

In the generic case, python `for` constructs loop over sequences. The [`range()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) and [`xrange()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange) functions can produce numerical sequences for you, these generate a number sequence in much the same way that a `for` loop in C or JavaScript would produce:

```
>>> for i in range(5):
>>>   print i,
0 1 2 3 4
```

but the construct is far more powerful than the C-style `for` construct. In most such loops your goal is to provide indices into some sequence, the python construct bypasses the indices and goes straight to the values in the sequence instead.

Comment: is'nt there a simple looping like in other languages. Y is it so complicated

Comment: @WebDeveloper: It's simpler looping; the complication lies in your new matrix needing initializing.

Comment: @WebDeveloper: Can you post a simpler example from any other language?

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw something else into the mix of answers, if you are doing *any* kind of matrix operations with Python, consider using [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/):

```
>>> import numpy
>>> matrix = numpy.matrix([
...     [1, 2, 3, 4],
...     [5, 6, 7, 8],
...     [9, 10, 11, 12]
... ])
```

The transpose is pretty simple to do:

```
>>> matrix.transpose()
matrix([[ 1,  5,  9],
       [ 2,  6, 10],
       [ 3,  7, 11],
       [ 4,  8, 12]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, what you want to do is a [matrix transposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose), which can be done this way:

```
 zip(*matrix)
```